# Resizing a user control

Tags: c++, winforms, c#-4.0

Im in the process of trying to create a rounded rectangle but decided to start with something a little simpler, an ellipse in this case. Unfortunately when i drag the custom control onto the Fprm1.cs[design] and try to resize it, nothing happens to the actual ellipse. Only when i got into the usercontrol[design] and resize it there does it change. I would appreciate it if someone could point out where i have gone wrong. Thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

namespace CustomPbar
{
    public partial class Pbar : UserControl
    {
        GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();

        public Pbar()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            path.AddEllipse(0, 0, this.ClientSize.Width, this.ClientSize.Height);
            this.Region = new Region(path);

            this.BackColor = SystemColors.ControlDarkDark;
        }

        private void MyForm_Layout(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.LayoutEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.Region != null)
            {
                this.Region.Dispose();
                this.Region = null;
            }

            path.AddEllipse(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);
            this.Region = new Region(path);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling it from the Resize event:

```
protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e) {
  using (GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath()) {
    gp.AddEllipse(this.ClientRectangle);
    this.Region = new Region(gp);
  }

  base.OnResize(e);
}
```